# how get page before? Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a question for the community that I can not find answers in the Internet.

If i use `var name =  this.GetType().Name;`, I get the name of the Page/Activity that I have now.

I need know the page that I had before this. how can I do?

Comment: You need to use the `Navigation` property on the `NavigationPage` you have set as main page. Without more of your code - saying more is beyond my abilities.

Comment: thanks for your attention, but I need to know the command to get the page before the current one

Comment: Read the documentation about navigation, and `NavigationPage` and you will have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the app navigation stack:

```
var navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;
var totalPages = navigation.NavigationStack.Count;
//currentPage is just the last Page of stack
//var currentPage = navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
//or
//var currentPage = navigation.NavigationStack[totalPages - 1];
var previousPage= navigation.NavigationStack[totalPages - 2];
```

Comment: can you explain better?

Comment: Whenever you navigate through your app pages, app's Navigation Stack gets updated and you can observe this stack in Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack; [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

Comment: Navigation stack is merely a "collection" of pages, a list of page generally speaking. Last page of this stack is current page that you're in app i.e lastPage = Stack[Stack.Count - 1], as you know the first element of arrays and collections start with 0.

Comment: does your solution work if I use the CarouselPage and Navigation.PushModalAsync (new ... ()) in the application?

Comment: Modal pages have a separate stack. CarouselPage itself can be a page in NavigationStack(not their items). What's your scenario? What do you want to achieve?